# Flask using thread to run code after/alognside return

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I am trying to run code after I return my template in flask

Here is sample code

```
@app.route("/hello")
def Hello():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=long_running_task)
    thread.start()
    return 'hello'

def long_running_task():
    time.sleep(5)
    return redirect("/goodbye")
```

Is this possible? Why when this code is ran it does not work as intended? /hello should load, then after 5 seconds it should redirect, but it never redirects and I believe the thread is never ran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it does work, but since in your `Hello` function you return 'Hello' after the thread start, the `return redirect("/goodbye")` never makes it to the browser. But the processing in the background works, you can add some print statements in the `long_running_task` code and see the flask console for yourself:

```
@app.route("/hello")
def Hello():
    thread = threading.Thread(target=long_running_task)
    thread.start()
    return 'hello'

def long_running_task():
    print("long task started")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("long task ended")
    return redirect("/goodbye")
```

Comment: Ah I get it now. But then is there any way to actually do the redirect? In my application, the thread task is constantly checking a database for any updates, and when an update happens I want it to redirect to a different page. Any ideas for how to accomplish this?

Comment: You cannot have 2 `return` steps, once 1 is executed Flask sends the response to browser and the transaction closes. I think your only option is to move all the code to the `Hello` function, because if you just start a thread and remove the `return 'hello'` then you will get in the browser the `TypeError: The view function for 'views.Hello' did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.` If you wanted to display a page saying "waiting for db update" then perhaps you should look into an Ajax call for catching that db update

Comment: meaning: step 1: you load a page with the spinner "waiting for db update" and step 2: with a javascript in that page, you make an ajax call to another regular route that will be checking for that db update, and with javascript you can handle the redirect to a new url. Hope what i describe is clear

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I used an alternative method, though. Used HTML code to refresh every 5 seconds, and in the code of flask i have every time the page is ran it checks the database, and if something changed it redirects to another page.